# Laravel where is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with Laravel Query.
I'm trying to get some results with join, but when I pass whereNotIn, it says like:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
> where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `products`.* from `products`
> inner join `merchants` on `merchants`.`id` = `products`.`merchant_id`
> where `id` not in (3) and `products`.`deleted_at` is null order by
> `merchants`.`rank` asc

So the code is:

```
$product_ids = [3];
$products = ProductHome::whereNotIn('id', $product_ids)
                ->join('merchants', 'merchants.id', '=', 'products.merchant_id')
                ->orderBy('merchants.rank')
                ->select('products.*')
                ->get();
```

But when I remove whereNotIn, or if it's empty, everything works fine, but it needs to be there. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please set table name with id eg. `ProductHome::whereNotIn('merchants.id', $product_ids)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `products` table in your `whereNotIn()` condition, just like you are doing in the `join()`:

```
$product_ids = [3];
$products = ProductHome::whereNotIn('products.id', $product_ids)
                ->join('merchants', 'merchants.id', '=', 'products.merchant_id')
                ->orderBy('merchants.rank')
                ->select('products.*')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because both the tables have an id column and SQL won't know which one to choose, Can you do something like this and check?

```
    $product_ids = [3];
$products = ProductHome::whereNotIn('products.id', $product_ids)
                ->join('merchants', 'merchants.id', '=', 'products.merchant_id')
                ->orderBy('merchants.rank')
                ->select('products.*')
                ->get();enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it after I posted a question :)